# Can noflo.js be used in a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, noflo

I'd like to use noflo.js's workflow co-ordination in a browser application. Is that possible?

If it's not possible, my bonus question is what is a workflow co-ordination library that does work in the browser, and allows external (i.e. not code) representations of the workflow?

Comment: Yes, there are even two [examples](http://noflojs.org/example/) for browser use. Specifically look into the [second one](https://github.com/noflo/dataflow-noflo).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that can be found in the framework examples.

Comment: @ArtjomB.Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. https://app.flowhub.io/ currently lists 7 client-side examples. ([app.flowhub.io aka noflo-ui](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-ui) is a more-full-featured example, but is in flux.)

https://github.com/noflo/noflo-browser-app/ is some new work that allows debugging of a client-side app in another window, browser, or device via WebRTC. Alpha demo, but it seems to work.